# Colorbox plugin installed but status report is not recognizing it

Tags: javascript

I have installed the Colorbox plugin version 5.1.14 in /sites/all/libraries/colorbox but on the status report page I get the following:

> You need to download the Colorbox plugin and extract the entire contents of the archive into the sites/all/libraries/colorbox folder of your server.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bugreport for module that verifies colorbox plugin version improperly, and should be posted in module's issue queue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Drupal needs to have a v in front of the version number:

Original code in jquery-colorbox-min.js

```
/*!
    Colorbox 1.5.14
    license: MIT
    http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox
*/
```

Changed to:

```
/*!
    Colorbox v1.5.14
    license: MIT
    http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox
*/
```

jedsmith13 https://www.drupal.org/node/1074474#comment-9138455

Comment: Hacking modules and libraries is a quick way for trouble. If anyone will use this answer, then forget it or leave site to another maintainer, site will fail after next colorbox library update - not good.

Comment: What is your fix for the situation?  I understand that this answer is a work-around (hack) but I don't see the alternative in the short term.  Yes, the best answer is for Drupal to recognize the library without the "v" but that means getting a patch approved for core.  Right now I need the site to work.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes what happens with these libraries is that the download you get from the library site (colorbox in this case) packages its code in a folder itself. For the master download of colorbox, for example, the code comes in a folder called colorbox-master. If you unpack it into

sites/all/libraries/colorbox

then the code ends up in

sites/all/libraries/colorbox/colorbox-master

What you may need to do is unpack it into

sites/all/libraries

and then rename

sites/all/libraries/colorbox-master

to be

sites/all/libraries/colorbox

Comment: Your answer does not solve the problem.  I do have the plugin in the proper directory.